# Cant' load .ogg music files into Eclipse project in Slick2D

Tags: slick2d

Hi I'm very new here and I,m learning how to use Slick2D game library. I'm using Eclipse Luna IDE for coding. Everything was working fine till now but when I tried to load a music with ".ogg" extension, the problem occured.

I try to load a music by this line of code
music = new Music( "res/game_music.ogg" );

An exception occurs like this,

```
AL lib: FreeContext: (000000000E2F08A0) Deleting 64 Source(s)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jorbis/Info
    at org.newdawn.slick.openal.OggInputStream.<init>(OggInputStream.java:35)
    at org.newdawn.slick.openal.OggDecoder.getData(OggDecoder.java:311)
    at org.newdawn.slick.openal.SoundStore.getOgg(SoundStore.java:835)
    at org.newdawn.slick.openal.SoundStore.getOgg(SoundStore.java:793)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Music.<init>(Music.java:135)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Music.<init>(Music.java:74)
    at main.Game.init(Game.java:48)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:390)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314)
    at main.Game.main(Game.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jorbis.Info
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
```

I can assure you that 
1. I've looked on the internet for enough time to find a solution and surprisingly I could not find anything helpful even though many other people have faced similar problems. 
2. the "res/game_music.ogg" is in the right place. I am new here and can't include pictures in my question otherwise I would include a screenshot to show that the file is in right place.

Important note:
I faced some confusions when setting up the project. I don't want to lengthen my question now so I'm not talking about that now. But if anyone here tells me that my problem here is related to lwjgl.jar/slick.jar/native files etc. then I will include it.
At this moment just know that before trying to load music, every other render/update thing worked fine.

Would appreciate any helpful answer.

Comment: Could be a ogm file which is not supported officially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include 2 jars in your project.

Download the Slick2D [archive](http://slick.ninjacave.com/), and then add `lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar` and `lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar` to your project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I collected an ebook and was learning from it. That stupid book didn't say anything about including these two jars you have mentioned for ogg files.