# Error when trying to load sound using OpenAL in Java

Tags: java, openal

I was watching this tutorial on making games using java and I was on the part where we import music to our game. However, when I try to load the sounds using a method created in this class:

```
package main;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.newdawn.slick.Music;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.Sound;

public class AudioPlayer {

    public static Map<String, Sound> soundMap = new HashMap<String, Sound>();
    public static Map<String, Music> musicMap = new HashMap<String, Music>();

    public static void load(){

        try {
            soundMap.put("click_sound", new Sound("res/clickSound.ogg"));

            musicMap.put("music", new Music("res/background_Music.ogg"));
        } catch (SlickException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static Music getMusic(String key){
        return musicMap.get(key);
    }

    public static Sound getSound(String key){
        return soundMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

i get an error that says this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jorbis/Info
    at org.newdawn.slick.openal.OggInputStream.<init>(OggInputStream.java:35)
    at org.newdawn.slick.openal.OggDecoder.getData(OggDecoder.java:311)
    at org.newdawn.slick.openal.SoundStore.getOgg(SoundStore.java:835)
    at org.newdawn.slick.openal.SoundStore.getOgg(SoundStore.java:793)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Sound.<init>(Sound.java:87)
    at main.AudioPlayer.load(AudioPlayer.java:18)
    at main.Game.<init>(Game.java:45)
    at main.Game.main(Game.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jorbis.Info
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

have I wrote something wrong? i imported the correct external jars and did everything that said in the tutorial. However, I keep getting this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454624/cant-load-ogg-music-files-into-eclipse-project-in-slick2d

Comment: Thank You VeryMuch! it solved my problem :)